# Angular2+ why i am getting Invalid Date

Tags: angular

my date value is 15.02.2018

i can not convert is date object. when try the error is Invalid Date.

how can i change default date format in angular2+ components

you can check  `jsfiddle.net/ridvanc/1hk7knwq/1326/`

Comment: show us what have you tried till now

Comment: don't add it here, edit your question

Comment: I wouldn't believe in my darkest dream that anyone in any universe would use mm/dd/yyyy instead of dd/mm/yyyy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Date constructor accepts Date in MM/DD/YYYY format, whereas you are using DD/MM/YYYY.

Angular provides a DatePipe for formatting dates.
You just need to import DatePipe from the common module.

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
```

Some examples : -

```
<!--output 'Jun 15, 2015'-->
<p>Today is {{today | date}}</p>

<!--output 'Monday, June 15, 2015'-->
<p>Or if you prefer, {{today | date:'fullDate'}}</p>

<!--output '9:43 AM'-->
<p>The time is {{today | date:'shortTime'}}</p>

<!--output 'Monday, June 15, 2015 at 9:03:01 AM GMT+01:00' -->
<p>The full date/time is {{today | date:'full'}}</p>
```

Comment: You are passing the date like given below, 14 is considered as Month which doesn't exist:
    processDate=new Date('14.02.2018');
Instead pass like 
    processDate=new Date('02.14.2018');